# Outputting Total Rows

Tags: t-sql

The query below is not being parsed by SQL Server and I can understand that the column name needs to be aliased which I have equally done. The idea behind the query is to output the count of rows using a CTE.

```
DECLARE @TotalRows AS INT = 0 -- OUTPUT
WITH orders AS 
(
  SELECT @TotalRows = COUNT(CustomerID),SalesOrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate 
  FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
  WHERE OrderDate = '2007/07/01'
)
SELECT c.CustomerID, 
       orders.SalesOrderID, 
       orders.OrderDate
FROM Sales.Customer AS c 
  INNER JOIN orders 
    ON c.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY orders.OrderDate DESC;
```

How do I modify the query to produce the desired retult?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you state the error...

Comment: Count of what?  And why does it need to be a cte?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT C.CustomerID, 
       O.SalesOrderID, 
       O.OrderDate
FROM Sales.Customer AS C 
     INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader O ON 
       C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
WHERE O.OrderDate = '2007/07/01'
ORDER BY O.OrderDate DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks. But from the query the count of rows are not outputted. I want to be able to output the row count using a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Output total rows or count of row is not clear

```
select c.CustomerID, 
       o.SalesOrderID, 
       o.OrderDate,
       count(*) 
  FROM Sales.Customer AS c 
  JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader o 
    ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
   and o.OrderDate = '2007/07/01'
 group by c.CustomerID, o.SalesOrderID, o.OrderDate
 order by o.OrderDate desc  

select count(*) 
  FROM Sales.Customer AS c 
  JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader o 
    ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
   and o.OrderDate = '2007/07/01'

select count(distinct(CustomerID))
  FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader o 
 where o.OrderDate = '2007/07/01'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible.

A query either returns a resultset or it assigns values to variables. Never both at the same time.

> Msg 141, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 A SELECT statement that assigns a
>   value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval
>   operations.